# Get multiple values from dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I get two values from a dropdown list generated from a stored proc to be used as a parameter? Example: ReportMonth and ReportYear. I can get the ReportMonth from the dropdown list but I'm unable to get the ReportYear.
`Response.Redirect("default.aspx?reportmonth=" + ddlSelectReport.SelectedItem.Value + "&reportyear=2013"`

Comment: Is `reportyear` in the same dropdown? A different dropdown? To say you didn't provide enough to answer this is an understatement.

Comment: @ethorn10 Yes. The sql table contains ReportID, ReportMonth & ReportYear. The `ddlSelectReport.SelectedItem.Value` grabs the ReportMonth. My concern is the year when 2014 arrives. Thank you.

Comment: Change it to a ListBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to create another dropdownlist for year.

```
Response.Redirect("default.aspx?reportmonth=" + 
   ddlSelectMonthReport.SelectedItem.Value + 
   "&reportyear=" + 
   ddlSelectYearReport.SelectedItem.Value)
```

Comment: Great. Let me try that and I'll let you know.

Comment: Update. It worked by adding another dropdown list. I was hoping to use only one dropdown list with two values, but this will work. Thank you.